# How to start Application in Wine From a terminal window

Tags: linux, debian, wine

I am running Wine on a Linux Server so as to run some old Windows Applications.

I now need to write a script to make sure they are running.

Is it possible to create an ssh connection to the server and start the application?

e.g. if I am on the desktop, open a terminal window and run

```
wine "Z:\home\user\Desktop\application"
```

the application opens. But If I connect by SSH and run

```
wine "Z:\home\user\Desktop\application"
```

I get:

```
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
```

I'm assuming I need to tell it *where* to start the application rather than just starting it, but can't see how to do this?

---

ADDITIONAL INFO:

I am currently working on a Windows PC, and connecting with Putty to the Linux/Wine server. (I also have a RDP connection so I can see the desktop).

Long term I will be running the script on another Linux server (MgmtSrv) that will make an ssh connection to the Linux/Wine server to manage it. The MgmtSrv does not have Wine installed, and does not have an X-Display set up.

Comment: Long term, do you need to see the Windows applications' windows? If so, where?

Comment: Yes, the windows Applications are 'visual' applications, so they will be running on the Linux/Wine server, hence the reason for installing the X-Display on that server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you surmise, you need to tell Wine where to display its applications. Since your Wine server has an X display, it's probably `:0`:

```
DISPLAY=:0 wine ...
```

should do the trick (assuming your X authentication cookies are OK; if they're not you'll get an `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE` error).

Comment: That makes sense. Unfortunately it still gives me the same error as initially

Comment: From the terminal window where you can launch the Wine application properly, what does `echo $DISPLAY` show?

Comment: that's got it. On the Desktop it came up as `:11.0`. So I then ran `DISPLAY=:11.0` in my (remote) terminal and my application opened. Cheers for that.

Comment: Thanks that's really works .

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your application type, you've the following approaches:

- If your application is console based (without graphics), run using [`wineconsole`](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Text_mode_programs_.28CUI:_Console_User_Interface.29) (not `wine`).
- If you've X server installed, you need to specify `DISPLAY` variable to point to the right screen.
- If you'd to run application via *X11 Forwarding*, [configure `X11Forwarding`](https://superuser.com/a/948200/87805) in your SSH config.
- If you want to run graphics program headlessly, consider installing [*X virtual framebuffer*](https://superuser.com/a/948200/87805).

Answer (score -3):

Just login as NORMAL user fixed this issue.

Problem:

```
/root *# wine .....
```

FIX:

```
/root # exit
```

Solution:

```
/normal_user> ./wine yourappname  OR ./wine64 yourappname
```